# Right align TextView using gravity in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to get an editText to sit on the right edge of my layout, with a button to its left, as follows:

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/FindClientLayout"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/third_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/half_height"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_below="@id/HeaderLayout"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fragment_separation"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/scrollViewRecommend"
    android:background="@drawable/login_border" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFindClient"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/find_client"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/Black" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editTextClient"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/input_text_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerClientList"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/input_text_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextClient"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDoFind"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/editTextClient"
        android:text="@string/find" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The button is invisible, and the result looks like this:

[image: Layout]

I assume the button is invisible because the editText is left-aligned and overlays it or pushes it out of the layout frame. Why is are the editText and spinner left aligned rather than right-aligned? Also, why is the editText not centered vertically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit you xml file like this and check for result

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewFindClient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/find_client"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editTextClient"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/input_text_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="text"/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerClientList"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/input_text_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editTextClient"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDoFind"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/editTextClient"
    android:text="@string/find" />
```

this should solve your problem which is , you are using gravity to place the edittext on right but gravity is actually use to position the content of view not the view itself.

If you still face problem leave a comment

Answer (score 6):

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
```

indicates the content in the edittext will be right aligned and in center_vertical postion

If you want to right align you can use `alignParentRight="true"` or `toRightOf="id_to_which_it_relate_to"`

Answer (score 2):

You can't align RelativeLayout child views with just gravity.
Try to use android:layout_centerVertical="true" and android:layout_alignParentRight="true" instead

Comment: Moreover the edittext should be aligned wrt to text view otherwise textview and edit text will overlap if android:layout_alignParentRight="true" used

Comment: In fact, using gravity is incorrect, as Ravi and @SKT pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

align Button to left of RelatativeLayout and TextView to right. Keep the EditText in between TextView and Button.